# How to set up css-modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

[Official documentation](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) way too complicated and not working for me. Does anyone know any good article how to set up `css-modules` with webpack?

[react-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-css-modules) didn't help either

**Update**

Here is my modules config. It was edited while trying to reach my goal, so it differs from original.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "react-hot-loader!babel-loader" },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader"
            }]
        }, {
            test: /\.png$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=[name]--[hash].[ext]',
        }
    ],
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    }, {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
    }]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple

You need style-loader, css-loader and set module mode.

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' 
}
```

Like that.
Where `[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]` indicates structure of your css classes that webpack will generate for you.

I recommend follow this guide, is really that simple.
https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo

Comment: that's what I did and still have my css classes without prefixes

Comment: can u share your webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

```
loaders: [{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
  }],
```

after `css-loader` you need add `?` then `modules` and so on.

In the component you need to import style:

```
import style from './App.css';
```

style - it's just object with properties which match to selectors.

And usage in component looks so:

```
const App = props => (   
<header className={style.header}>
   <Link to="/" className={style.link}>Awesome blog</Link>
</header>);
```

App.css looks so:

```
.header {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```